# Enable and Disable Delayed Expansion, what does it do?

Tags: batch-file

I've seen `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` & `SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in many batch files but what do the commands actually do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SETLOCAL and ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION usage question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-usage-question)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`enabledelayeexpansion` instructs `cmd` to recognise the syntax `!var!` which accesses the `current` value of `var`. `disabledelayedexpansion` turns this facility off, so `!var!` becomes simply that as a literal string.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Using `!var!` in place of `%var%` accesses the changed value of `var`.

Answer (score 7):

Copied from [How do you use SETLOCAL in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704223/how-do-you-use-setlocal-in-a-batch-file/13707636#13707636) (as dbenham indicated in his first comment).

Suppose this code:

```
If "%getOption%" equ  "yes" (
   set /P option=Enter option: 
   echo Option read: %option%
)
```

Previous code will NOT work becase %option% value is replaced just one time when the IF command is parsed (before it is executed). You need to "delay" variable value expansion until SET /P command had modified variable value:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If "%getOption%" equ  "yes" (
   set /P option=Enter option: 
   echo Option read: !option!
)
```

Check this:

```
set var=Before
set var=After & echo Normal: %var%  Delayed: !var!
```

The output is: `Normal: Before  Delayed: After`

Answer (score 1):

With delayed expansion you will able to access a command argument using FOR command tokens:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=0
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 9) do (
 set /a counter=!counter!+1
 call echo %%!counter! 
)
endlocal
```

Can be useful if you are going to parse the arguments with for loops

It helps when accessing variable through variable:

```
 @Echo Off
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set _server=frodo
 Set _var=_server
 Set _result=!%_var%!
 Echo %_result%
```

And can be used when checking if a variable with special symbols is defined:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "dv==::"
if defined !dv! ( 
   echo has NOT admin permissions
) else (
   echo has admin permissions
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**ALSO** note that with `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` you cant echo **!!!!!!** so:

```
echo my sentence! 123
```

will be outputed as:

> my sentence 123