# Set file names as variables in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a question how to set multiple files as variables in batch file? I trying to do something with below script:

```bat
move c:\*.gpg q:\
for %%F in ("q:\*.gpg") do (set file=%%~nxF)
if exist q:\*.gpg echo done copying files: %file%
```

Above works fine only with one file. If there are more than two it only echos one of them. How can I echo in one line all the files that where copied?

Comment: First you should group both your commands: `set` and `if` in the same block (to be both executed by each `for` iteration). Second, it seems a [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) problem. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278456/enable-and-disable-delayed-expansion-what-does-it-do) (or tons of others revealed by _Google_-ing).

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems with your code

```bat
for %%F in ("q:\*.gpg") do (set file=%%~nxF)
if exist q:\*.gpg echo done copying files: %file%
```

First, you're assigning new values to the variable file each loop and then overwriting it every time without doing anything. Therefore after the loop `file` will only contain the value in the last loop. Move the `echo` part to inside the loop instead

Another problem is that variables are expanded at parse time by default. You need to [enable delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use `!` instead of `%` to make it expand at runtime

```bat
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("q:\*.gpg") do (
    set file=%%~nxF
    echo done copying file: !file!
)
```

If you want to echo all files at once then set the `file` variable to contain the list of files

```bat
for %%F in ("q:\*.gpg") do (
    set file=!file!, %%~nxF
)
echo done copying files: %file%
```

The file existence check is redundant. You can check the exit code after moving and exit if the files weren't moved.

Answer (score 2):

The variables are not constant so remember to activate the expansion delayed variable, here the expansion of the variable `file` must be delayed.

**Delayed Expansion** will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the **`SETLOCAL`** command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables can be referenced using **`!variable_name!`** (in addition to the normal **`%variable_name%`** )

**Delayed variable expansion** is often useful when working with **`FOR`** Loops, normally an entire **`FOR`** loop is evaluated as a single command even if it spans multiple lines of a batch script.
This is the default behaviour of a **`FOR`** loop:

**Example :**

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: count to 5 storing the results in a variable
set _tst=0
FOR /l %%G in (1,1,5) Do (echo [%_tst%] & set /a _tst+=1)
echo Total = %_tst%


C:\> demo_batch.cmd
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Total = 5
```

Notice that when the **`FOR`** loop finishes we get the correct total, so the variable correctly increments, but during each iteration of the loop
the variable is stuck at it's initial value of 0

The same script with **`EnableDelayedExpansion`**, gives the same final result but also displays the intermediate values:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
:: count to 5 storing the results in a variable
set _tst=0
FOR /l %%G in (1,1,5) Do (echo [!_tst!] & set /a _tst+=1)
echo Total = %_tst%

C:\> demo_batch.cmd
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
Total = 5
```

Notice that within the for loop we use **`!variable!`** instead of **`%variable%`**.

And your batch script can be written like that :

```
@echo off
Set "Ext=*.gpg"
set /a Count=0
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("q:\%Ext%") do (
    SET /a Count+=1
    set "file=%%~nxF"
    echo Done copying file [!Count!] : !file!
)
SET /a "COUNT_TOT=%Count%"
ECHO.
ECHO Total of [%EXT%] files(s) : %Count% file(s)
pause
```