# Why Windows version was checked in the batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, operating-system

```
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal
```

Hi have a batch script and I wonder why is checking **OS** version? Are there differences in batch syntax with **Windows 95/98**?

I am with Windows 7 and `echo %OS%` is `Windows_NT` why?

Comment: Windows 7 is a continuation of the NT line. All the modern Windows are :) The last non-NT version was 98 SE/ME or some such, since Win 2000/XP, everything is NT. Except for Windows RT nowadays, perhaps.

Comment: @Luaan the last non-NT Windows is Windows ME

Comment: OK. That answers 2nd part of my question. But the first?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I thought we decided to forget everything about Windows ME. But oh well, my mistake :D

Comment: ok but is there difference in shell language in NT and non NT versions?

Comment: it depends on what your script is doing. Each version of Windows introduce a lot of new commands or options so it's not backward compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setlocal` doesn't work on non-NT systems, as simple as that.

It's not exactly easy to find, but you'll see that it is in documentation of the command processor for NT 4.0, Windows XP etc., while it's missing in 95, 98 etc. (which use the MS-DOS command processor rather than the NT shell).

Windows 7 *is* a Windows NT system, just like Windows 2000, XP, or Windows Server 2008, for example. The version number is in fact a continuation of the line - Windows NT 4.0 being followed by 2000 (5.0), XP (5.1+), Vista (6.0), 7 (6.1) etc.

Comment: Related questions: [How do you use SETLOCAL in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704223/how-do-you-use-setlocal-in-a-batch-file) and [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd) (found by Google: "cmd vs command")